# Jupyter Notebook's default page appears nothing

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I installed python 3.7.2 version and jupyter notebook with pip command.

All programs and modules are successfully installed and enter the "jupyter notebook" into my folder's domain.

And I copied the URLs and paste to my chrome browser.

[image]

But, default pages didn't appear anything.

[image]

How can I fix this problem?
I need your help...

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/4467
I encounter similar trouble. So I just do 3 steps:

1. uninstall Jupyter Notebook 5.7.6:
   conda uninstall notebook
2. install old version:
   conda install notebook=5.7.4
3. After lauching Jupyter Notebook 5.7.4:
   Press CTRL+R or CTRL+Shift+R to clear the cache

Then Jupyter Notebook works normally now.
Hope it's helpful to you.